# Writing a macro which will know the current state

Tags: math-mode, macros

I wish to write a macro which will be able to tell whether the machine is currently in mathmode or not. The pseudo-code is:

```
IF IN MATHMODE{
%commands
}
ELSE{
%other commands
}
```

Is such a thing possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\relax\ifmmode
  stuff
\else
  stuff
\fi
```

You may want to declare it with `\DeclareRobustCommand` as you need to protect this from expanding at the wrong time.

Comment: @David I would add a `\relax` at the start here, just to be on the safe side.